# Mailchimp spam alert: HTML & subject

Tags: spam-prevention, html, mailchimp

I'm using Mailchimp for sending newsletter campaigns. Usually, messages get the inbox but I have noticed sometimes they run to spam folder. In addition I have received the following alert from Mailchimp:

"The HTML code you're using contains some unusual attributes that are causing spam filters grief. Simpler is better for email HTML. You may need a designer to help you with this one.
If you change your subject line case to Standard Heading Style, your email will get through."

I'm not an expert in HTML for email but I know how to make well structured HTML websites. However, when I inspect the HTML from the email campaigns, based on one Mailchimp template, I can't find nothing weird. Furthermore, I don't understand what can I do with the subject line case. Am I supposed to add h1 tags inside the title tags?

I give you the head of one campaing in case it helps.

```
<head>
    <meta name="twitter:image:src" content="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/81ac16e7cd7930ee7060eff5e/images/fd492080-1ca5-4666-8966-058aac8e0d30.png"><meta name="twitter:description" content="Selección de productos en Tecnología, Estilo de Vida y Formación Online :)"><meta name="twitter:title" content="Te recomiendo que visites Gremyo.com!"><meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"><meta property="og:type" content="article"><meta property="og:description" content="Selección de productos en Tecnología, Estilo de Vida y Formación Online :)"><meta property="og:image" content="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/81ac16e7cd7930ee7060eff5e/images/fd492080-1ca5-4666-8966-058aac8e0d30.png"><meta property="og:title" content="Te recomiendo que visites Gremyo.com!"><meta property="og:url" content="http://eepurl.com/bywdlb">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>*|MC:SUBJECT|*</title>
    /*Here there are the styles*/
</head>
```

Do you know what the alert points and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: I can't provide much insight into what makes the body of an HTML email problematic (by and large I _hate_ HTML email), but the "case" they're talking about with your subject is the letter case. `You Should Use Title Case` or `Use sentence case`, but don't use `ALL UPPER CASE` or `all lower case` and limit the amount of punctuation you use.

Comment: I'm not sure that this question is a good fit for this site. Granted, Mailchimp can be considered a web app, but the issue is really the format of the email message for maximum success for an email campaign and not using the functions of the site. That said, I don't think there's a Marketing Stack Exchange, though. Not every question has a place in Stack Exchange.

Comment: Sorry if the question doesn't fit the site purposes. If somebody reading this knows a better site, I'd like he or she tolds me. 
@AlE. thank you for your advice. Sometimes we capitalize all names, adjectives and verbs of the subject. Probably we shouldn't.